# CURL in Linux Works in CLI but throws Error "curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application; Unknown error" in script file

Tags: linux, curl

Ran the below command from terminal it works

```
curl -i -u "username:password" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -X POST -d '{"ObjectName" :"testobject","Status" : "Success"}' \
  https://xxxx-xxxx.xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:443/ic/api/xxx/v1/flows/rest/xxxx/1.0/status
```

But when  it is wrapped in script.sh as shown below

```
curl -u \"$1\" -H \'Content-Type: application/json\' -X POST -d \'\{\"ObjectName\":\"$2\",\"Status\":\"$3\"\}\' $4
```

it shows the below error

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application; Unknown error
dhclient-exit-hookspRI.log plugin088693904 plugin382717443 script.sh systemd-private-59e972836edd4f0a8990ff436c48aa5e-chronyd.service-VWWmQC
```

I am running the script as shown below:

```
sh script.sh xxxx:xxx  abc.txt success \
  https://xxxx-xxxx.xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:443/ic/api/xxx/v1/flows/rest/xxxx/1.0/status
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The host is not reachable.. the DNS is unable to resolve the host in question

Comment: You do not need `:443` in your host

Comment: Note also that `$2` and `$3` won't be expanded in `'{"ObjectName":"$2","Status":"$3"}'` because of the single quotes. Compare for example the output of `echo "$HOME"` with `echo '$HOME'`.

Comment: AND to speed up your development work, learn to debug your script with `set -x` to turn on debug-output and `set +x` to turn it off (yes, counterintuitive, `+` and `-` ;-) ) . Using that, you would have seen that `$2` and `$3` hadn't been expanded. Good luck.